# PixiJS renderTexture anti-aliasing

Tags: javascript, graphics, pixi.js

I am currently working on an app that draws circles to a PIXI renderTexture using the same approach as the Pixi scratch card example (https://pixijs.io/examples/#/demos-advanced/scratchcard.js).

```
var app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: 0x2c3e50
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
startup();

let traceCircle = function (centerX, centerY, radius, angle) {
    let result = [];
    result[0] = centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angle));
    result[1] = centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angle));  
    return result;
}

function startup()
{
    const renderTexture = PIXI.RenderTexture.create(app.screen.width, app.screen.height);
    const renderTextureSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(renderTexture);
    
    app.stage.addChild(renderTextureSprite);

    let brush = new PIXI.Graphics();
    brush.beginFill(0xffffff);
    brush.drawCircle( 0, 0, 5);
    brush.position.set(300, 300);
    brush.endFill();
    // Listen for animate update
    let angle = 0.0;
    app.ticker.add(function(delta)
    {
        coords = traceCircle(300, 300, 100, angle)
        brush.position.set(coords[0], coords[1]);
        app.renderer.render(brush, renderTexture, false, null, false);
        angle += 0.01;
    });
}
```

Here is the code working in PIXI Playground : https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/sdaKkXRHrR3vzJf6VyiQm

The code works as expected, but the brush edges appear pixelated as there is no anti-aliasing being applied to the texture.
What methods are there for implementing anti-aliasing in this case?

my app is ultimately going to be drawing many circles at once so efficiency is a concern.

I also ideally need to be able to vary the brush radius.

Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a way to achieve what I was looking for using Pixi-filters

by adding

```
renderTextureSprite.filters = [new PIXI.filters.FXAAFilter()];
```

before adding the renderTextureSprite to the stage.